# Will a shared Access front-end prevent data corruption?

Tags: database, ms-access, corruption

I have created an Access DB with a nice front-end, however the db is not split.

The DB is in a network location and it is shared between 5-8 users. Data loss occurs from time to time: some stored queries just disappear when sending their output via e-mail through a macro, for example.

I have read on several sites that to prevent this, I should split the db and make each user work on his/her frontend.

However, in the context I am it would be much better to have the users working on a single shared file.

The question is: If I split the database and make the users share the front-end file, would I be preventing data loss/corruption?

Comment: Old to see things just disappear.  The main benefit from splitting your front end and back end logic is if your front end, which is typically used the most, gets corrupted you wont loose your data.  You should always keep a copy of your front end stored away where no one but you can find it.

Comment: Also, these types of questions are usually frowned upon on this site.

Comment: *"If I split the database and make the users share the front-end file"* - Did you actually mean "split the database and make each user work on his/her [local copy of the] frontend"? Please [edit] your question to clarify. As it stands now, your question is confusing.